# What is the max size of a Azure Key Vault secret value?

Tags: azure-keyvault

I want to store some larger secrets in Azure Key Vault.

So i wonder what the max size of a value that can be stored as a secret in Azure Key Vault is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52480.azure-key-vault-overview.aspx) it looks like the limit is 25kb.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/about-secrets